# Limits at infinity involving trigonometry

Tags: limits, trigonometry, infinity

I was wondering as I stumbled upon a question like this:
$$
\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)^+}\frac{\tan(x)-x}{\tan(2x)+3}
$$

$\tan(x)$, when $x$ is approaching $\pi/2$ is $-∞$, and I know that from the graph, but is there any other way that this can be done without looking at the graph? Maybe using a calculator, or drawing a table?

EDIT:  I would also like to ask why is $\tan(2x) = 0$ and not $-∞$ like $\tan(x)$.

Comment: You must know the graph of standard functions to be able to solve these kind of things. Or at least know that $\tan(x) =\sin(x) / \cos(x) $. That is my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that $$\tan(2x)=\frac{2\tan(x))}{1-\tan(x)^2}$$ and $$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Tan (2x) evaluates the tangent of 2*x, not of x. Thus, tan lim tan(2x) as x-> pi/2 evaluates tan(pi), which = 0.
Also, as Dr. Graubner said in his answer, use the trig identities to rewrite the function to find the proof analytically.